# java.lang.SecurityException: App not allowed to read or update stored WiFi Ap config (uid = 11529)

Tags: android

I want to fetch my Hotspot's SSID. I Implemented below code

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 Method getConfigMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
 WifiConfiguration  wifiConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getConfigMethod.invoke(wifiManager);
 final String ssid = wifiConfig.SSID;
```

which gives me an error java.lang.SecurityException: App not allowed to read or update stored WiFi Ap config (uid = 11529)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It doesn't work starting from Android 8; I think here is an useful response for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46393359/6835932

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.SecurityException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724057/java-lang-securityexception) You‘re probably missing the permissions the activity needs in the manifest.